# Ajax delete for comment is not reloading the partial + rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have got ajax comment submit and delete, submit works perfectly but delete is not working.

Below is my code :-

**Controller**

```
def destroy
  @status_update = StatusUpdate.find(params[:id])
    if @user == current_user
      if @status_update.destroy
        respond_with do |format|
          format.html do
            if request.xhr?
              render :partial => "users/post_status_update", :locals => {:user => @user}, :layout => false, :status => :created
            else
              redirect_to @user
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.delete-status-update')
    .on("ajax:beforeSend", function(evt, xhr, settings){
    })

    .on("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      $('.status-partial').replaceWith(xhr.responseText);

    })

});
```

**View**

```
.status-partial
  -@user.status_updates.latest.limit(5).each do |status_update|
    .row-fluid.cycle-status-update{:class => cycle("dark", "light")}
      .row-fluid
        .span11
          = status_update.status
        .span1
          .delete-status-update-link
            %strong= link_to "X", [@user,status_update], :remote => true, :method => :delete, :class => "delete-status-update"
      .row-fluid
        .time-ago-in-words
          ="#{time_ago_in_words(status_update.created_at)} ago"
```

Problem is status partial is not getting replaced once I click on the delete link, after refreshing the page ajax delete works for the first time then it again stops to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with syntax of `.on` used in javascript file, it does not work like `.live`. Changing the syntax to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on("ajax:success", "#create_status_update_form", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      $('.status-partial').replaceWith(xhr.responseText);
      $('.comment-text').val('');
    })

});
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are needlessly complicating everything. Your destroy controller could be simple as follows:

```
def destroy
  @status_update = StatusUpdate.find(params[:id])
  if @user == current_user
    unless @status_update.destroy
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end
end
```

In your views, instead of calling through $.ajax, try a rails `link_to "action", action_path, remote: true`

Name your html view file as destroy.js.erb.

These can be its contents:

```
$('.status-partial').html(<%= @user.generate_new_content.to_s %>);
```

Rails will take care of the rest. When you click on the link, the element with class 'status-partial' will have its html content replaced with "some new content".

It's a good practice to separate your HTML and AJAX responses, and Rails provides a convenient way to do it. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you would do

```
respond_with do |format|
format.js
```

and then have a file called `destroy.js.erb` to place the javascript that should fire after a deletion

Comment: destroy.js.erb should be in comments view?